# Cant connect to Parse.com after update 'Android Support Libary' v22

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

I using Android Studio and I have a problem to connect to Parse.com after update 'Android Support Libary' to ver. 22.
Project thats worked before now not working.
After hours of searching and testing I decided to open a clear project only for this, but the problem still exist.

**MainActivity Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   List<ParseObject> data;
   List<String> nameList;
   String[] name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String appId = " ********* ";
    String clientId = " ********* ";
    Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(), appId, clientId);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("test");
    try {
        data = query.find();

    }catch (ParseException e){
        Log.i("myParseExceptionLog", "Can't connect to test table at parse");
    }

    nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0 ; i < data.size(); i++){
        nameList.add(data.get(i).getString("name"));
    }
    name = nameList.toArray(new String[nameList.size()]);

    TextView myTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
    myTV.setText(name[0]);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifast.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="shachar.com.parsetest" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    }
```

I know I need to dependencies my jars in build.gradle but look at the note.
Anyway at its appears in Project Structure and I can imports libs from parse in my classes.
When I tried to dependencies in build.gradle and sync the Manifat deleted.

[image: Project Current Libs]
[image: Project Structure]
After 2 min of black screen, the app remembered to crash and bring me NullPointerExpiton(beacuse 'data' is null).

**LogCat Errors**

```
03-17 16:46:17.686  18427-18427/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: shachar.com.parsetest, PID: 18427
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{shachar.com.parsetest/shachar.com.parsetest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at shachar.com.parsetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
```

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 16:46:18.212      672-695/? E/﹕ Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
03-17 16:46:18.212      672-695/? E/﹕ error : 2, No such file or directory
03-17 16:46:18.245     672-3024/? E/Sensors﹕ new acc setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000) err! go to hwmsen
03-17 16:46:18.323     672-3023/? E/﹕ Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
03-17 16:46:18.323     672-3023/? E/﹕ error : 2, No such file or directory
```

What i'mdong worng?

What I'm missing?

Something cahnge with the new 'Android Support Libary' version?

**Edit:**

I just did another test, I downloaded a complet exmple od parse from their website with all the setting and last parse version. I reinstall Android Support Libary and still not working

Comment: Can you show line number 39 in MainActivity?
According to parse docs it's better to subclass `Application` and initialize it in `onCreate`.

Comment: I know I'm doing at in all my apps. Its  lik this now for the exmple.  **line 39:**  for (int i=0 ; i < data.size(); i++){ **---** 'data' its null beacuse of my problem

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it looks like you have null value at line 39, can you add the line numbers to this so that we can see where this null value is being thrown?

Comment: I know that, I said it at the main post. and for line 39 just answred to   MightySeal

Comment: Okay okay I see. Honestly I would go ahead and download the newest parse starter project and then have the keys in the separate application file like they have in default. MightySeal is right when he refers to the Application subclass. When I was messing around with the Parse.initialize() I pretty much had to have it in a separate file to get the damn data to pull from Parse

Comment: the last ver of parse work diffrently. Here you can see only one file at last ver u have 7 file and 2 folders... lot of new function that I dont need. Anyway I tried it but i dont know how to use it...

Comment: I just did another test, I downloaded a complet exmple od parse from their website with all the setting and last parse version. I reinstall Android Support Libary and still not working

Comment: Hmmmm so I would go to your app on Parse.com and then click and download the quickstart guide project. I think the project is called ParseStarterProject. Honestly If you really want to fix this and just get that loop going I would (1) download most recent android studio (2) download a ParseStarterProject (3) implement the loop by using the same data with same key values. I hope this helps man lemme know if youre still getting stuck

Comment: ParseStarterProject is complete exmple I ment. So I did what u said and still not working. The only thing I have in mind is Delete all Android Studio, plugins... and reinstall everting, but I want to be sure I treid everthing else. Its\ my dead end solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if  `for (int i=0 ; i < data.size(); i++)` produces NullPointerException it's definitely because `data` is null, so you have to check if `data` is null.

Comment: Thats what I said... data is null cuz the app cant connect to parse.
I didnt get any error about the connction to parse and still data value is null.